# what is the minimum react version for @fluentui/react-northstar?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

[This project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/tab-personal-sso-quickstart/ts/package.json#L16) using react ^17.0.1" with fluentui/react-northstar

but I am getting error as below  package.json while running **npm i @fluentui/react-northstar**. what can be the reason ?

> npm i @fluentui/react-northstar        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm
> ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> While resolving: client-app@0.1.0 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2 npm
> ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root
> project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> react@"^16.8.0" from @fluentui/react-northstar@0.60.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@fluentui/react-northstar npm ERR!
> @fluentui/react-northstar@"*" from the root project

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: React 16 and after will do...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like older versions of the fluientUI library require React16, which is the error you are hitting as you are running React17.

I have a project which uses react 17 and was able to install the following versions:

```
"@fluentui/react-icons-northstar": "^0.64.0",
"@fluentui/react-northstar": "^0.64.0",
```